# How to plot appropriate contour or quiver diagrams from given axisymmetric data?

Tags: matlab, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to solve axisymmetric incompressible Navier Stokes Equation in cylindrical coordinate system using Sullivan vortex model in MATLAB.

**Here is the sample code:**

[drive.google.com/open?id=0B-rqPMNkwWbNV2NBOURhUzZEcWM](http://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-rqPMNkwWbNV2NBOURhUzZEcWM)

If r denotes radial distance and z denotes axial distance.

u, v & w are velocities in r, theta and z direction respectively, depending on 'r' and 'z' only, having no dependence on theta and hence are 2-D matrices.

p is pressure depending on 'r' and 'z' only, having no dependence on theta and hence is a 2-D matrix.

U, V, W & P are corrected data in r, theta and z direction respectively, depending on 'r' and 'z' only but are 3-D matrices as theta direction too is included but the parameters do not vary in theta direction.

I tried the following but none of it worked.

```
[th,R]=meshgrid(theta,r);

[x1,y1] = pol2cart(R,th);

contour(x1,y1,P(:,:,34),500)

%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx



[x1,y1] = pol2cart(th,R);

contour(x1,y1,P(:,:,34),500)

quiver(x1,y1,U(:,:,34),V(:,:,34))

%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

contour(R.*cos(th),R.*sin(th),P(:,:,34),500)
```

Now, I am trying to plot contour and quiver plots from this data but the plots tend to vary with theta also. While in some other cases, I got an incomplete circle.

Maybe, I am not able to assign proper direction to the velocity vectors.

Please suggest me some appropriate way of doing this.